# Unable to match function definition, template

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I have a class called **Box** inherited from the base class **Entitiy**

In Entity, I have `getWeight()` function;

```
double Entity::getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
```

I want to override this function in the Box class. so I did this;

```
template <class T>
double Box<T>::getWeight() {
    return weight + inWeight;
}
```

But it gives me this error

```
Error   C2244   'Entity::getWeight': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
```

Why am I getting this error?

**EDIT:** Entity class

```
class Entity {
    public:
        Entity(double weight_in, double length_in, double width_in);
        Entity();

        double getWidth();
        void setWidth(double);
        double getLength();
        void setLength(double);
        double getWeight();
        void setWeight(double);

    protected:
        double weight;
        double length;
        double width;
};
```

Box class

```
#include "entity.h"

template <class T>
class Box : public Entity{
    public:
        Box(double weight_in, double length_in, double width_in, double maximumAllowedWeight_in);
        Box();
        Box(Box<T>&);
};
```

Comment: How do you declare `Entity`? Please show the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the function inside the class definition before you can define it outside. (Or you could just define it inside the class.)

```
template <typename T>
class Box : public Entity {
    double getWeight();
};
```

would make your definition valid.

You might want to consider marking it `const`.

Answer (score 2):

You should do what Alan said also for the Entity class. And if you expect the getWeight() method from Box to be called, when you call it from a Box type object declared as an Entity type object, you should add the virtual keyword so it actually overrides (late binding):

```
class Entity {
    float weight = 10;
    virtual double getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }
};
```

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function